# Bulk insertion using Laravel without any loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a code portion where online classes added based on class and division. I am adding `onlineclasses` successfully, but I need to send notification to the students when `onlineclass` are adding. I get students based on class and division. My problem is I dont want to use the loops to insert these students notification record based on the for loop of student list. I need each row inserted without any loop.

```
            $Recordings = new OnlineClass();
            $Recordings->teacher = $request->input('name');
            $Recordings->subject = $request->input('subject');
            $Recordings->title = $request->input('title');
            $Recordings->description = $request->input('description');
            $Recordings->status = '1';
            $Recordings->class_id = $request->input('classes');
            $Recordings->sub_class_id = $request->input('subclasses');
            $Recordings->date = $request->input('date');
            $Recordings->start_time = $request->input('startTime');
            $Recordings->end_time = $request->input('endTime');
            $Recordings->thumbnail = $filename;
            $Recordings->save();
    $students=Student::where('class',$request->input('classes'))->where('division',$request->input('subclass'))->get();
```

Notification Table Structure
['id','Notifi_from','studid','content','status']

Comment: please help me to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [::insert()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts) for mass save

```
$insertArray = [];

foreach ($students as $student) {
    $insertArray[] = [
        'teacher' => $request->input('name'),
        'subject' => $request->input('subject'),
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'status' => '1',
        'class_id' => $request->input('classes'),
        'sub_class_id' => $request->input('subclasses'),
        'date' => $request->input('date'),
        'start_time' => $request->input('startTime'),
        'end_time' => $request->input('endTime'),
        'thumbnail' => $filename
    ];
}

OnlineClass::insert($insertArray);
```